# Howto show comment count by post in post?

Tags: posts, comments, count

I would like to show comment count IN the post (not in post meta), is there a snippet how to do this or a wordpress internal shortcode?

Comment: Do you mean to display it in the post's content? Please show the current relevant code that you've tried so far, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
add_filter('the_content','my_comment_count');

function my_comment_count($content) {

    $content .= get_comments_number(get_the_ID());

    return $content;
}
```

Comment: Please, explain _why_ this helps the OP instead of just posting the code. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Please add the following code into your theme's functions.php

```
    add_shortcode( 'comment_no', 'commno' );
    function commno(){

        $number= get_comments_number(get_the_ID());

        return $number;
}
```

and then you can use shortcode `[comment_no]` to display number of comments where you like.

Comment: Does not work for me :-/

Comment: Where have you put this code @jo

Comment: I am sorry, that was my fault. meanwhile I got it working!